# Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just don't get it.

I have this interface.

```
export interface Activity {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  date: Date | null;
  description: string;
  category: string;
  city: string;
  venue: string;  
}
```

and then I have this function:

```
  get activitiesByDate(){

    return Array.from(this.activityRegistry.values()).sort((a, b) => 
      Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date));
  }
```

But I still get this error:

```
Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

What I do wrong then? And how to correct it?

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to see what the `Interface` and the `activitiesByDate` getter have to do with each other. `activitiesByDate` returns an array. Where is the React.js code? And what part causes the error?

Comment: on the face of it - looks like your interface wants date to be a Date object or Null, but you're giving it a string instead. Date.parse(a) - a is a string.

Comment: .parse is what it does:  Parses a string containing a date, and returns the number of milliseconds between that date and midnight, January 1, 1970.

Comment: `Date.parse` accepts a `string` as an argument, whereas you're trying to pass it a `Date | null` type argument and that's why you're getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error you are getting here is quite explanatory, but I would try to explain better:

Javascript's `Date.parse()` method parses a string representation of a Date, it's better explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

This means that the argument type that `Date.parse()` accepts must be of type `string`. It also accepts arguments that are instances of `Date` (which is an object) in javascript.
`Date.parse()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC

Examples:

```
console.log(new Date() instance of Date); // true
console.log(Date.parse(new Date().toString())) // gives the right answer

console.log(Date.parse("01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT")) // works properly
```

What typescript is telling you in this case, is that you shouldn't be assigning a value whose type could be `Date` or null to a method that expects a value of type `string`.

So, what can you do?
Since you know that the type of the variable `Date` on `Activity` could be of type `Date | null`

I would suggest you do something like this:

```
if(a.Date && b.Date) {
  Date.parse(a.date.toString()) - Date.parse(b.date.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the example yourself? Because you're still gonna get an error, since you're passing a `Date` type to the `Date.parse` method, but it only accepts a `string` type.

Comment: @Kapobajza I was updating the answer when your comment came in. Updated now. Thank you :+1

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of typescript being super-extra-sure your code is bulletproof. In your interface you have defined the `date` property as possibly `null`.

```js
date: Date | null;
```

That means in this piece of code:

```js
Date.parse(a.date)
```

It is checking for two possibilities:

```js
Date.parse(null)
```

or

```js
Date.parse(<type Date>)
```

Both fail. `Date.parse` is expecting a `string`. In order to keep typescript happy,

you need to ensure that `a.date` is *always* a string. This means you need to account for `null` *and* you need to convert your date object to a string, while also accounting for `null` when doing the conversion of a date object into a string. This can be done with optional chaining and nullish coalescing

```js
Date.parse(a.date?.toDateString() ?? new Date().toDateString) // or whatever default value you want
```

But that being said, `Date.parse` is not recommended. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) What is your use case? Surely, there is a better way to go about implementing your intent.